# What is the maximum length of a Windows XP drive label?

Tags: windows-xp, drive-letter

Question is pretty much self-explanatory.  I'm working with naming USB drives if that matters.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[32 characters in NTFS, 11 in FAT.](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/label.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: Is there a way to find this for exFAT?

Comment: link broken. new link?

Comment: For exFAT it’s the same as for FAT (probably for compatibility reasons).

Answer (score -1):

The max length for a drive *label* name is, according to [this link](http://www.real-knowledge.com/labeldsk.htm), 11 characters.

Comment: the post is spam, the links is a commercial, @admin please remove

Comment: It wasn't when I first posted it. But, yeah, the domain seems to have changed hands, and then changed again. It's up for sale now. Still, 11 in FAT :)

Comment: please remove the link, or change to a meaning and stable one like Wikipedia or so